# Is there a column type for laravel migration that generates random unique number

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image: Screenshot of migration]

I want to generate a random unique number at $table->string('number'); , replacing string

Comment: You are talking about data in table! And that on screen shot is the structure of the table. So these are 2 very different things.

Comment: Please post code snippets using the markdown editor rather than images of code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has [Faker](https://fakerphp.github.io/) baked in for data generation, but this is typically used in either a [seeder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/seeding) or a [factory](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories) and not done in a migration and probably would not be advisable to perform such things in a migration.

If you do not have a standard `default` value for your column and want to provide a random value when a record is created, consider using one of the [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events) or [Eloquent Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers) to hook into the model lifecycle events (i.e. `creating` or `created`) to perform whatever action(s) you desire at that stage.

If you're looking to insert a random number when a record is created, consider using the [`random_int()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) function.